# Angular - Useless Error after attempting HTTP Post request to a URL

Tags: angular, http, post

I have the below HTML Angular materials table;

```
<div div class="main-search-user-name">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Search Select User</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let getddusers of getusers" [value]="getddusers">
              {{getddusers.value}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="SearchUser(selectedItem)">Search</button>
</div>
```

And the following user.component.ts inside of the export class but outside of the constructor;

```
public SearchUser(selectedItem: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  const body = JSON.stringify(selectedItem);
  console.log(body)
    return this.http.post(environment.BASE_URL + 'posturl/postdisplayname', body, {'headers':headers}).subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.selectedItem.Id, selectedItem.value = result;
    }, (error: any) => {
       console.error(error);
    })
  }
```

I can pass a payload from Postman to the URL posturl/postdisplayname so I know it's active, and it gets passed to the database via Dapper ORM. But, passing values from my angular materials table into the user.component.ts and then to URL posturl/postdisplayname yields the below error.

[Cannot read properties if undefined (reading 'post')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I370j.png)

```
core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')
    at UserActivityComponent.getUserByID (useractivity.component.ts:91:15)
    at UserActivityComponent_Template_button_click_44_listener (useractivity.component.html:66:71)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:14963:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15001:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:461:38)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:1)
```

So I think I understand that the issue is with the way I have written the `SearchUser()` function and maybe the POST method too. But after researching for quite a while I'm unable to make any progress. Is there a way forward, as it's a stumbling block at the moment. Any suggestions welcomes at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code in useractivity.component.ts:91 ? The error says that you are trying to get a "post" property of something that is undefined.

Comment: Is http an instance of HttpClient? is being injected in the constructor?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo the error was from a previously failed attempt yet returning exactly the same error. But it it defined, confirmed with postman, I feel I'm not passing something to the method in the correct format.

Comment: I understand that the backend it's working but the error maybe it's related on how you expect to get the response, SearchUser returns an Observable ( I advice not to use "any" but to create entity objects ), where do you subscribe to that observable? To understand the error it is necessary to check all the code that can cause it

Comment: @a_e yes, http is an instance of HttpClient within the constructor. However my GET methods, defined within the constructor work perfectly. But because the function SearchUser is outside of the constructor I suspect that this may be the cause?

Comment: try to: Remove the public from the method, just SearchUser.

Comment: Ok, I see that the subscribe is within the SearchUser function, you should check if "this.selectedItem.Id, selectedItem.value" are evaluated before you use them somewhere else..

Comment: @SergioRinaudo thanks for this. I'll take a look at entity objects as I'm not sure that I've covered this yet. I never subscribe to that observable which is making me wonder why it's in there at all to be honest.

Comment: @a_e I gave it a go but still get the same error.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo just confirmed that both this.selectedItem.id, this.selectedItem.value get evaluated and return values. I only wrote them to the console in developer tools but they are being passed. So I think it's likely what you've suggested.